# Desperate with the GoogleMaps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

For a week I'm stuck with this problem, and not managing to proceed. I only getting the activity with a blank map.

First I followed the instructions on [google maps developers site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), but didn't succeed. Then I tried to copy some code from the google play service mapdemo, and still failed.
I tryed everything I found here and other sites in order to make a SupportMapFragment, but nothing helped.

The google mapdemo itself runs well on my debugging device (samsung s6500).

thanks

Logcat:

```
07-21 22:12:33.819: W/dalvikvm(13123): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 27
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (718)
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/w;' failed
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/aq/as; (5347)
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Link of class 'Lmaps/aq/as;' failed
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ag/l; (4576)
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): Link of class 'Lmaps/ag/l;' failed
07-21 22:12:34.019: E/dalvikvm(13123): Could not find class 'maps.ag.l', referenced from method maps.ah.an.a
07-21 22:12:34.019: W/dalvikvm(13123): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4420 (Lmaps/ag/l;) in Lmaps/ah/an;
07-21 22:12:34.559: E/Adreno200-ES20(13123): **** 13302: glUseProgram(0)
07-21 22:12:34.759: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 0
07-21 22:12:34.759: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
07-21 22:12:34.769: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 1
07-21 22:12:34.769: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
07-21 22:12:34.779: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 0
07-21 22:12:34.779: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
07-21 22:12:34.799: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 1
07-21 22:12:34.799: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
07-21 22:12:34.819: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 0
07-21 22:12:34.819: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
07-21 22:12:34.839: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2c7938, bufid: 1
07-21 22:12:34.839: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(13123): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
.
.
.
....
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="iOphir.mapapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <permission
        android:name="iOphir.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="iOphir.mapapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
                   <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIza-----------"/>
        <activity
            android:name="iOphir.mapapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="iOphir.mapapp.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity

```
package iOphir.mapapp;

import iOphir.mapapp.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: Does your `fragment` from the layout file  have the `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` attribute?

Comment: I noticed it just after sending, edited the log and problem. thanks.

Comment: If you're getting a blank map you should check the logcat for an explanation. If it's an authorization error then make sure you've signed the app with the proper key(many question related to this) for your package and the certificate with which you signed it. Also, uninstall/reinstall it after each attempt.

Comment: Managed to make some changes in the google API console that gave me a difrent catlog. I'll be happy to get some explenations.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Now I feel dumb.

My package was .mapapp, but after the SHA-1 fingerprint I entered it finishing with .mappapp .

Oh... I fell great to get over it but an asshole because of geting in to it.

Thanks for whoever tried.